# retrieving data from list in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve data from a list of data. Each element has the following structure (not the actual code):

```
   class PathPatternStringsWithDDV {
       List<string> PathPatternString;
       List<Point> DDV_XY;
       string FromState;
   }
```

I need to compare the first element of `PathPatternString` and the last element of `DDV_XY` , for this I am currently using the following line of code:

```
 (List<PathPatternDDXY_WithProbability>) rtnlist = 
              allPathPatternDDXY_WithProb.Where(a => a.PathPatternString[0] == ptrn 
                                                    && a.FromState == fstate 
                                                    && a.DDV_XY[a.DDV_XY.Count - 1].x == _x 
                                                    && a.DDV_XY[a.DDV_XY.Count - 1].y == _y
```

This gets me an error ("delegate does not take one element"). Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the class structure in code, your describings are unclear to me.

Comment: Please show a sscce.org

Comment: A [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a nice-to-have.

Comment: thanks, i have put the structure of class

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman 404

Comment: Still not clear what the code you want to fix does. Please post a http://sscce.org Try using https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Your first snippet wouldn't compile, you cannot cast the target of an assignment while assigning a value to it in a single statement.

Comment: You could massivly improve readability if you omit those (unneccessary) `If`-statements within your properties, they won´t do anything useful. Simply retain the statements within the `else` (without the keyword `else` of course)

Comment: Actually the PathPatternDDXY class derive from the class mentioned above.(pathPatternString). do you think that this might be the cause of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to:

```
 IEnumerable<PathPatternDDXY_WithProbability> rtnlist =
 allPathPatternDDXY_WithProb.Where(a => a.PathPatternString[0] == ptrn
                                       && a.FromState == fstate
                                       && a.DDV_XY[a.DDV_XY.Count - 1].X == _x
                                       && a.DDV_XY[a.DDV_XY.Count - 1].Y == _y
                                     );
```

Comment: or simply `var rtnList = ...`

Comment: "In C#, the general guidelines says to not always use var because it can sometimes hurt the readability.": http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271923/whats-the-tradeoff-for-type-inference

Comment: Actually the PathPatternDDXY class derive from the class mentioned above.(pathPatternString). do you think that this might be the cause of problem?.. i tried as you mentioned but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ToList()` method like this:

```
var rtnlist = allPathPatternDDXY_WithProb.Where(.... .....).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually the PathPatternDDXY class derive from the class mentioned above.(pathPatternString). do you think that this might be the cause of problem?

Comment: The result of LINQ expression would be of type IEnumerable<Type> where Type is the same type as allPathPatternDDXY_WithProb

Comment: if you need smth like this class A : class B  {}  and later in code:        List<A> lst = List<B>.Where(condition).ToList() you have to upcast it explicitly. Smth Like :  List<A> listA = new List<A>();    List<B> listB =  List<B>.Where(condition); foreach(B item in listB) {  listA.Add(item); }

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all.

Actually i didn't include a reference for Point class, at the top of my project.
now i include using System.Drawing;
and the error disappear.

thanks for your help

Comment: You wrote the error is "delegate does not take one element", not "unresolved reference"...